# How to sort by proximity?

Tags: sql

I'm building an app that recommends people to other people based on how frequently they've been to the same place.
So for a given person A (the one you want to give a suggestion), I have a table of all others persons and the amount of time they've been to a place. i.e, I get this:

```
idPerson     |     idPlace     |     nbTimesPersonWent   |  nbTimesPersonAWent
    10       |       1         |         3               |        10
    11       |       2         |         1               |        22
    12       |       1         |         11              |        10
    13       |       3         |         8               |        2
```

What I'm struggling with is finding which of these `idPerson` is the "best" person to recommend to A.

Is there a way (preferably pure SQL), to sort this table from "closer" value of `nbTimesPersonWent` and `nbTimesPersonWent` to "less close" values?

Comment: You have two columns with the name nbTimesPersonWent, is that intended, if yes, what is the difference?

Comment: Nice eye, i typed too fast, just edited my answer

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the proper objective is. Let's assume that place `1` was visited `3` times by person `B1` and `3` times by person `A`, i.e. their preference for place `1` is equal, which can be expressed by `0 = |3-3|` On the other hand, let's assume that place `2` was visited `100` times by person `B2` and `12` times for person `A`; their preference for place `2` differs, but the chances to meet would have been potentially `12 = min{100,12}`. Is person `B1` or person `B2` the better match for `A`?

Comment: I would say person b1, even if you could argue that going 3 times in a place is not a sign of a habit ...

Comment: This question was put on hold, because you are asking for a way to write the SQL, but it shows you haven't really thought about what the SQL shall do exactly. Once you define the rule how the SQL shall sort the persons, you will probably notice that the SQL itself is easy to write.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the following tables

Person:

```
id
```

Place:

```
id
```

Visit:

```
person_id, place_id, time_spent
```

Now you must choose which way you will sort people that are interesting to a particular person a.

Many different sort functions exists. For any person of interest `a`, you can rank any other person b based on many different criteria. For example:

`f(a,b) = Sum of min_time(a,b,p) for all places p that both a and b have visited`, where `min_time(a,b,p) = minimum of the time a and b have spent at place p`

`f(a,b) = The number of places that both a and b have visited`

The difference between the two methods is that the first consider the time spent at different places and that the second only considers the number of places commonly visited. You can also define functions that limits the impact of having spent much time the same place, compared to distributing that time over multiple places.

If you can specify an exact ranking criteria, I will be happy to help you write a query for it.

UPDATE: Here is an example of sorting by the 2nd ranking criteria. That is, by the number of visited places in common: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b56745/1/0

Comment: In my particular case, the time spend in a given location is not quite relevant, long story short it is about playing games in places, so all people will spend roughly the same time.
The second one is actually exactly what i want, the more common place you have, the better the reccomandation

Comment: @Rogue I would not recommend having a table for each user which stores all other users if there is not a very good reason for doing so. If you have n users it will require n tables, each with n-1 elements. That is roughly n^2 entries with a lot of redundancy. I have made an example of how I would design a such system here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b56745/1/0
The query finds all other users except the one with id = 3, and ranks them in decreasing order of common places visited.